# WooCommerce showing subcategories and products together

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce plugin in my Wordpress site.

I've made some categories and I'm showing them in a wordpress page with the following snippet:

```
[product_categories parent="0" orderby="name" order="ASC" hide_empty="1" ids="1,2,3"]
```

Under the first category, I've also made 3 subcategories that I'll call 1A, 1B, 1C to be more clear.

I've a lot of products of the "id=1 kind" and some of them belong to one of those subcategories and some other products belong to the parent category (id=1).

I'd like that when the user opens the categories page and clicks to the (id=1) category he can see, in addition to the three subcategories, also the products that belongs to id=1.

Actually, it is showing only the three subcategories and zero products of the parent category; I'd like to see together the subcategories and the products belonging to id=1, is it possibile?

thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the woocommerce settings . Go to

> Woocommerce setting -> Products -> Display ->
>
> Shop page display -> Select Show both
>
> Default Category display -> Select Show both.

It might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did what you wrote. 
I had 20 products belonging to category "1"; I moved one of the 20 products to 1A subcategory and what I see now clicking on category 1 is one subcategory (1A) containing the only product that I moved; the 19 products left and belonging to category 1 are not showed :(